# How to feed the array_repeat function count value from another column?

Tags: pyspark

How to feed the array_repeat function count value from another column:

```py
>>>import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>>dftmp = spark.createDataFrame([('ab',)], ['data'])

>>>dftmp.select(F.array_repeat(dftmp.data, 3).alias('r'))
>>>dftmp.show()
+----+------------+
|data|      repeat|
+----+------------+
|  ab|[ab, ab, ab]|
+----+------------+
```

Is there a way to use the repeat count value based on another column? e.g.

```py
>>>dftmp.withColumn('len',  F.length(F.col('data')) )
>>>dftmp.withColumn('repeat', F.array_repeat(dftmp.data, F.col('len')))
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Expected Result

```
+----+------------+---+
|data|      repeat|len|
+----+------------+---+
|  ab|[ab, ab]    |  2|
+----+------------+---+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an **`.expr`** :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dftmp.withColumn('repeat', F.expr("""array_repeat(data, len)"""))
```

Or you could just **`calculate length`** in there too like:

```
dftmp.withColumn('repeat', F.expr("""array_repeat(data, length(data))"""))
```

Comment: super! Any idea why my code doesn't work? what does `F.expr` do differently vs plain function ?

Comment: The expr(sql line) basically sends it down to spark sql engine that allows u to send cols to parameters that could not be cols using pyspark dataframe api.